# Twitter API GET Trends 404 error

Tags: twitter, http-status-code-404

I check trends regarding to REST API of twitter. [get trends](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/trends/%3awoeid)
Generally it works well. But sometimes I get 404 error.
After some minutes it comes back.

Error code is:

```
{"errors":[{"message":"Sorry, that page does not exist","code":34}]}
```

Does anyone had this issue? What would you recommend ?
Please check this link, it gives 404 now.
https://api.twitter.com/1/trends/1.json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how often are you accessing this call - are you sure you are not breaching the rate limit?  If not breaching, this could possibly be an issue on the twitter end and you would need to handle the error message, use the previously cached response for your application till you get an updated feed from twitter.  hope this helps

Comment: I thought about rate limiting or IP blocking. I didn't use this call more than 10 times an hour. Does the last link doesn't give you an 404 ?

Comment: it gave me 404 when I tried it.  I am assuming there is nothing wrong with your implementation since you mentioned it works under nromal conditions and the URL for twitter is correct

Comment: @trante : For rate limiting it's 420, not 404.

Comment: @air-dex thank you for info. output page had an 34/404 error code. Do you have any idea?

Comment: I'm curious - what happens at that time when you change the woeid and retry?

Comment: I found out that the reason is rate limit of IP. I couldn't find it because I was getting a 404 rather than 301.